# Forcing Windows Mobile 6 application to run in landscape mode

Tags: windows-mobile, rotation, landscape

I am writing an application for Windows Mobile 6.1, and I would like the application  always run on landscape mode, regardless of the screen rotation. Does anyone have any idea? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could always watch the device's [ScreenOrientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.systemsettings.screenorientation.aspx) and change it back when you see it altered.  As a user, I'd really dislike that behavior though.